# Hide Highcharts error's in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

I may have a strange request, i would like to hide highcharts error's into console

Especially the #15th because it's normal that my data aren't sorted.So let me know, if you know a way to do that.

Comment: You shouldn't hide error logs, you should resolve them so they don't show in the first place.

Comment: In fact, i only have 1 kind of error, it's that my data arrays aren't sorted.But it's intended by what i have to do (a circle into a line graph)

Comment: @Pierolain hiding the error is one thing, but having a working chart is another. Highcharts does not guarantee the chart is accurate if the data is not sorted, I am pretty sure some of the data in the chart is missing when you get that error and that would not be acceptable for your users. Please sort your data and pass to highcharts, either sort on server side, else do it in javascript before passing to highcarts.

Comment: It's an approximation, so it is not very important to have sorted data. Moreover, the rendering is in line with customer expectations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of `line` use `scatter` type with `lineWidth: 1`. Scatter series doesn't require sorting.

Or for that one extra point, use separate series with `linkedTo` option.

Or, if you really want to chart-options remain as they are, use snippet below:

```
(function(H) {
    H.seriesTypes.line.prototype.requireSorting = false;
})(Highcharts)
```

And demo: http://jsfiddle.net/rsft60sg/

Just to be on the same page, without modifying source code you won't be able to prevent Highcharts from throwing that error.

Comment: Great ! Your snippet of code worked ! Thanks, i don't have to scroll console anymore ! :)